# What general term can be used to describe KVC/KVO, Bindings and Objective-Cs dynamic messaging?

Tags: cocoa, naming-conventions, terminology

I'm struggling to find a simple term to describe the collection of "soft" technologies used in Cocoa development:

- KVC/KVO
- Bindings
- Dynamic messaging
- Message forwarding
- Dynamic typing

Is there a general term that can be used to lump all of them together?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamism?

(Wow, Stack Overflow hates brevity. Here's some padding!)